# Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am new to the power shell scripting. I am trying to delete all files except one folder and one file. I run this script by using jenkins it showing error called " Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt  functionality is not available." And i am trying to run this script in powershell window but it asking `Confirmation [Y/N]`. I need to run this script by using jenkins please help me.

[image: Image of prompt]

```
$Path = "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work"
$exclude = @("*.old", "*directory.map") 
Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item  -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop| echo Y
```

Comment: I try this script it is still asking confirmation [Y / A / N].

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Recurse parameter to the remove command.

Like that:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: If I use Remove-Item -Recurse -Force it is showing this type of error  " Could not find apart of the path"

Answer (score 0):

guiwhatsthat is correct your code should like this;

```
$Path = "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work"
$exclude = @("*.old", "*directory.map") 
Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: I try this command it is showing this type of error "Could not find apart of the path"